# Problema ao tentar executar um projeto usando react-native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Eu estou fazendo um tutorial de react-native mas ao tentar executar o projeto usando o comando:

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Eu recebo as seguintes mensagens de erro:

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'GasAgilMobile'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
  >   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-bintray/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom?referrer'.
  >   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Eu estou usando a versão 10 do JDK. A versão do meu android studio é a 3.5.3.

Eu tentei colocar essas url's no navegador para a url https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.4.2/gradle-3.4.2.pom o arquivo é baixado corretamente, para a segunda recebo o seguinte erro:

```
{
```

"errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "Could not find resource"
  } ]
}

Eu li que isso pode ser um problema de certificados. Mas não sou um usuário avançado em java e não tenho idéia de como resolver isso.

Comment: Qual sistema operacional você está utilizando? Pelo erro parece ser configuração de ambiente. Você configurou todo ambiente android  ? Variáveis de sistema, caminho para o sdk.  
Pesquise por android environment pode ser esse o problema.

Comment: Sim @LeandroSena. Configurei todo o ambiente de acordo com a documentação na página do react native. O sistema operacional que estou usando é o Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema. Realmente era um certificado que estava faltando. Segui os procedimentos desse post: http://magicmonster.com/kb/prg/java/ssl/pkix_path_building_failed.html. O problema era que meu java estava sem o certificado correto para o dominio: https://www.google.com/chrome/. Eu exportei o certificado do dominio e adicionei ao meu keystore e tudo está funcionando agora.

Comment: É necessário reiniciar o PC após fazer o procedimento descrito no link que passei acima.